# Do both male and female hops need to be grown side by side?

Tags: hops

I am interested in growing my own hops for decoration and brewing - mostly brewing ;-).

Do I need to purchase both male and female plants to get flowers?  My spouse who is a gardener pointed out this possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you do not. Only the females produce cones, and pollinated cones are not desirable.  Buy some rhizomes in the spring, plant them in a location that can meet their requirements (lots of light, lots of *height* and support for bining), and within a year you'll have beautiful hop bines and cones.